# RewriteMap activation

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How to activate RewriteMap in apache ?
I tried to run rewritemap in httpd config  when I restart apache, it says that 
"RewriteMap not allowed here"

i tried to google and go to apache but couldn't find a way to activate it.  anyone know?  thanks. :)

Comment: How about more detail? What's the name/path of the file you put the RewriteMap directive in? Any <Location>, <Directory>, <VirtualHost> etc. sections?

Answer (score 2):

The [*Context* information](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) tell you where you can use a directive. For [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) it says *server config* or *virtual host*.