# Convert to lowercase in a mod_rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like URLs like server.com/foo to be case-insensitive.
But server.com/foo actually gets mod_rewrite'd to server.com/somedir/foo

(Assume that all the files in "somedir" are lower case.)

So the question is, how to accomplish a mod_rewrite like the following:

```
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/?$  somedir/convert_to_lowercase($1)
```

PS: Here's a handy mod_rewrite cheat sheet -- http://dreev.es/modrewrite -- though it fails to answer this particular question.

PPS: Thanks to 
[Bee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58164/bee)
and
[Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams)
for all the help with this.
Also, here's a related question:
[RewriteMap activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703709/rewritemap-activation)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, put the following line in the `<VirtualHost>` section of your .conf file.
(For me that lives at `/etc/httpd/vhosts.d/00foo.conf`.)

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

You can replace `lc` with any name you want.
Then restart apache, which you can do with `sudo service httpd restart`.

Finally, add this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lc:$1}
```

Comment: Works here. Did you bounce httpd?

Comment: Probably not. What does that mean?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Ignacio.  I updated this answer with explicit instructions about what to put where and about restarting apache.

Comment: Be advised: This may not work as advertised. The first part is correct. Put the RewriteMap statement in the .conf file.

However in the .htaccess file, you may need one more statement; "RewriteEngine On"

This is what finally worked for me. 

`RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]  
RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]`

Comment: "add this in your .htaccess file:" - although the directive as posted will only work in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context.

Answer (score 14):

```
RewriteMap tolower int:tolower
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/?$  somedir/${tolower:$1}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, it now matches what I found elsewhere on the web in the meantime, but it's still not working for me.  I didn't understand your other comment about bouncing httpd.

Comment: I tried adding the above to my .htaccess and restarting httpd, and it is bringing the whole domain down. The error log says: "Rewritemap not allowed here". Where specifically am I supposed to put the Rewritemap statement? The documentation I'm finding shows it as two consecutive lines, like above. (I just stuck it in .htaccess right above the specific RewriteRule).

Comment: @Bee: The docs say "server config, virtual host", which means right in the main config stream or within a `<VirtualHost>` directive. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Comment: Sorry we're so dense about this stuff. I see from the link you provided (thanks!) that the RewriteMap line is not allowed in .htaccess.  I tried putting in the <VirtualHost> section of /etc/httpd/vhosts.d/00server.conf but when I restart Apache it complains that RewriteMap is not allowed here.

Comment: That's really odd. I have it working in a `<virtualHost>` section just fine here, so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it worked there after all!  I'll update my answer with more explicit instructions about this.  If you want to do the same then I can just delete my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would make it a 301 redirect, NOT a URL rewrite, for SEO purposes:

```
RewriteMap tolower int:tolower
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/?$  somedir/${tolower:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: A 301 without a cache expiry header is very bad practice because it gets cached *for ever* in browsers.  You'll be living with its effects for years.  Change `R=301,L` to `R=301,L,E=limitcache:1` and add a `Header always set Cache-Control "max-age=3600" env=limitcache` directive.  That'll limit caching to 1h while still giving you the SEO advantages of a 301 redirect.

Comment: A `301` redirect is, by definition, _permanent_, thus it can be cached indefinitely by default. If you expect the redirect not to be permanent, then use `302`.