# How to convert text to lowercase URLs using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to set up 301 redirects in my .htaccess file so URLs like

```
http://example.com/Foo

http://example.com/Foo/Bar

http://example.com/Foo/Bar/Blah
```

change to

```
http://example.com/products/foo

http://example.com/products/foo/bar

http://example.com/products/foo/bar/blah
```

There are a discrete number of "Foo" cases which I can target with RewriteRule ^Foo, but how to append the "products" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add this line in `<VirtualHost>` section *OR* at the end of your httpd.conf file:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Then have these rules in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews  
RewriteRule ^(Foo.*)$ /products/${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

- R=301 for sending back 301 to browser
- L for marking it last rule

Comment: This works but I have to specify the hostname like so 

`RewriteRule ^Foo(.*)$ http://example.com/products/foo$1 [R=301,L,NC]`

Also I end up with 

`http://example.com/products/foo/Bar`

Is there another rule I should run to convert to lowercase before running this rule?

Comment: If you are not redirecting to a different host then you won't need `http://example.com` in the rules above. And for lowercasing I modified rules above, please try them.

Comment: Rewrite Map in .htaccess causes 500 Internal Server Error. Does that need to go in httpd.conf instead?

Comment: Oh sorry, should have made it clear. Yes that line goes into `<VirtualHost>` section of `httpd.conf`. Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923658/convert-to-lowercase-in-a-mod-rewrite-rule for more. Or simply add this line `RewriteMap lc int:tolower` at the end of `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: No probs. I have to get someone else to tweak httpd.conf later as it's not my server but looks like it will work. Thanks!