# 301 Redirect .htaccess not working

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Hi guys i need help with 301 redirect using .htaccess

`http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/11&name=ben`

to be redirected to

`http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/11`

So far I have tried this

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2/dir3/\d+&(.+) /dir1/dir2/dir3/$2 [R=301,L]
```

it works but redirects me to

`www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3 without the number(11)`;

The second one is to redirect (dir/China to dir/china), (dir/London to dir/london) - Uppercase to lowercase

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(dir1/dir2/dir3/\d+)\&.+$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

**For lowercase conversion:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(serviced-apartments/.*)$ ${lc:$1} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Assuming RewriteMap for `lc` is correctly defined in Apache config.

Comment: Didn't work for me..display error message saying "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: Yes that's very close, error message is gone. The problem now is all the 111, 222, 33 values redirect to 1, 2 and 3 respectively. It should be in this form: http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/11&name=ben to http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/11, http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/21&name=ken to http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/21 and so on

Comment: That seems to be working OK. Thanks a lot anubhava. What could I have done without you. Also I have another query, to redirect from all matching uppercase files to lowercase path (e.g: dir/London to dir/london)..

Comment: Upper case to lower case will require you to make a change in Apache config. Do you have access to that?

Comment: Yes I do have access to the httpd.conf file

Comment: Ok for lowercase see this answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740022/how-to-add-text-to-urls-using-htaccess/5740137#5740137

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work for me. In the conf file I have; <VirtualHost *:80>
 RewriteMap lc int:tolower
</Virtualhost> and in htaccess I have Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews  
RewriteRule ^(dir1.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]. I would ideally like the  to redirect all www.example.com/dir1/File to www.example.com/dir1/file

Comment: Assuming Apache has been bounced after adding `RewriteMap` line you can use this rule `RewriteRule ^(dir1/.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]`

Comment: Hmm ok, try this rule: `RewriteRule ^(?=.*?[A-Z])(dir1/.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]`

Comment: It redirects all to home page now

Comment: That was actually tested code on my side. Try in a different browser.

Comment: could it be from my virtual host conf? I have done everything and it still wouldn't work. <VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(?=.*?[A-Z])(serviced-apartments/.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Yes it could very well be. I will edit the answer for one last attempt. If it doesn't work open a new question to get better answers.

Comment: I have figured it out. I removed slash from dir1/ to dir and it worked. Thanks alot

Comment: sorry to border you again, how would you redirect www.example.com/mylist-12 to /our-list, www.example.com/mylist-110 to /our-list

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^mylist-[0-9]+$ /our-list [L]`