# rewriting URL to all lowercase

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have this rewrite rule in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?(.*)$ /$1.php/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+) /api/$1_$2.php
```

How can I modify this to change everything in my URL to lowercase?

i.e. This:

```
www.mysite.com/ThisURL/SHOULD/be_all_lowercse
```

Should be

```
www.mysite.com/thisurl/should/be_all_lowercase
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert to lowercase in a mod_rewrite rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923658/convert-to-lowercase-in-a-mod-rewrite-rule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a RewriteMap of type `int` (internal) referencing the `tolower` function, and call it where you want to do the lowercasing:

```
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?(.*)$ /${lc:$1}.php/${lc:$2} [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+) /api/${lc:$1}_${lc:$2}.php}
```

Comment: Hi Mark. I get a 500 error when I use the sample above. Any idea why?

Comment: probably have to use only variables as function arguments.  try above.

Comment: Still a 500 error. I have the general idea now. I'll play with it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This [article](http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/) describes how to do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```