# Apache's mod_rewrite failing to remove trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

I have a XAMPP Apache server, and have added a configuration file to rewrite URLs with a trailing slash and redirect to their slash-less counterparts.

Therefore, a url like `http://example.com/the-audio/` gets redirected to `http://example.com/the-audio`. The problem is, it's not working when the directory name is only one word.

So, `http://example.com/audio/` does not get it's slash removed. This is really strange for me, and checking the logs it appears as though the rule isn't matched in this case.

Here's my rule (only one in the file)

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)\/+$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

And this is the error dump

**error.log**

```
[Wed Jan 11 22:13:32.729812 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1688:tid 1904] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:52432] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#ba8340][rid#29a2190/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/tecnoedu/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/tecnoedu/audio/ -> audio/
[Wed Jan 11 22:13:32.730312 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1688:tid 1904] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:52432] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#ba8340][rid#29a2190/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/tecnoedu/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'audio/'
[Wed Jan 11 22:13:32.730312 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1688:tid 1904] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:52432] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#ba8340][rid#29a2190/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/tecnoedu/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/tecnoedu/audio/
[Wed Jan 11 22:13:32.730312 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1688:tid 1904] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:52432] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#ba8340][rid#33046a0/subreq] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/tecnoedu/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/tecnoedu/audio/index.php
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

Comment: Is audio a real directory?

Comment: Yes it is, that may be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your log `/audio/` is an existing directory. So your rule wouldn't run since the first condition stops it running on existing directories. Remove the first condition to resolve it.

Also, to do this on existing directories, you will need to turn `DirectorySlash` off, or the server will add the slash back in itself. Note that there is [some security concern with that](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash).

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I can, thanks! Any idea how to prevent the security issue of directory listing? If not, I'll do my research.

Comment: Yes turn directory auto indexing off and test without the forward slash to make sure that's working. Not something I have experience of doing but from reading the security advisory that should cover it.

Comment: I've covered it, now I have [**another issue**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659112/how-do-i-use-mod-rewrite-to-both-redirect-and-rewrite-a-directory), I leave it here as I have no way to contact you.

Comment: No problem, added a comment which will hopefully help.