# How do I use mod_rewrite to both redirect and rewrite a directory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Don't flag this as a duplicate unless you know what you are doing. Some questions look similar, but aren't what I'm looking for.

If a user hits `example.com/friendly-folder` it should be *internally redirected* to `example.com/system-folder`.

However if a user hits the old `example.com/system-folder` it should be *externally redirected* to the new name `example.com/friendly-folder`.

So, basically, the directory URL must always be friendly, but pointing to the old one. I believe if I just made two rules without any condition it would get stuck in an infinite loop.

I've tried this in my **.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^friendly-folder(.*)$ system-folder$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /system-folder
RewriteRule ^system-folder(.*)$ /friendly-folder$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Which effectively *internally redirects* from the friendly folder to the system one, but doesn't *externally redirect* from the system folder to the friendly one.

Any ideas? While you are at it, if you have a method that also works for redirecting and rewriting *files* it would be much appreciated.

### Update

Now i've tried this configuration:

```
RewriteRule ^friendly-folder(.*)$ system-folder$1 [NC,END] 
RewriteRule ^system-folder(.*)$ friendly-folder$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

And I'm getting this error log:

```
[Sun Jan 15 18:40:49.765190 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 3936:tid 1896] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:50822] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#a92bb8][rid#2a52150/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/system-folder/ -> system-folder/
[Sun Jan 15 18:40:49.765691 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 3936:tid 1896] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:50822] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#a92bb8][rid#2a52150/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/] applying pattern '^friendly-folder(.*)$' to uri 'system-folder/'
[Sun Jan 15 18:40:49.765691 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 3936:tid 1896] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:50822] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#a92bb8][rid#2a52150/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/system-folder/ -> system-folder/
[Sun Jan 15 18:40:49.765691 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 3936:tid 1896] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:50822] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#a92bb8][rid#2a52150/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/] applying pattern '^system-folder(.*)$' to uri 'system-folder/'
[Sun Jan 15 18:40:49.765691 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 3936:tid 1896] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:50822] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#a92bb8][rid#2a52150/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/] rewrite 'system-folder/' -> 'friendly-folder/'
[Sun Jan 15 18:40:49.765691 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 3936:tid 1896] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:50822] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#a92bb8][rid#2a52150/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/] add per-dir prefix: friendly-folder/ -> C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/friendly-folder/
[Sun Jan 15 18:40:49.765691 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 3936:tid 1896] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:50822] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#a92bb8][rid#2a52150/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/friendly-folder/
[Sun Jan 15 18:40:49.765691 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 3936:tid 1896] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:50822] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#a92bb8][rid#2a52150/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/] escaping http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/friendly-folder/ for redirect
[Sun Jan 15 18:40:49.765691 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 3936:tid 1896] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:50822] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#a92bb8][rid#2a52150/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/] redirect to http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/friendly-folder/ [REDIRECT/301]
[Sun Jan 15 18:40:49.771194 2017] [core:error] [pid 3936:tid 1896] (20023)The given path was above the root path: [client ::1:50822] AH00127: Cannot map GET /C:/xampp/htdocs/urls/friendly-folder/ HTTP/1.1 to file
```

Comment: No, *.htaccess* is inside of the parent of those folders.

Comment: It looks like it should work as an approach, although I would just drop the RewriteCond and replace the L flag with END on your first rule, so other rules aren't processed if it matches. The problem you have is probably the caret "^" at the start of your RewriteCond just before "GET" or some other issue there, you could just make the pattern "/system-folder/" if you want to stick with that approach.

Comment: @SuperDuperApps You can see the error trace in the updated attempt.

Comment: You removed the forward slash at the start of the second rewriterule's replacement which is what is breaking it. Put it back! :)