# How to ignore case in regexp mapping in a .htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I have now is the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/*$ x/$1.html [L,NC,END]
```

This would point:

```
/abcd  to  x/abcd.html
/ABCD  to  x/ABCD.html
```

which would not be fine on a Unix file system that is case-sensitive.

What I want is to point both variations to:

```
x/abcd.html
```

How can that be achieved?

Similar questions have been asked about this on Stack Overflow, but none seems to have addressed the issue of regexp back referencing on a Unix system.

Comment: [Convert to lowercase in a mod_rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923658/convert-to-lowercase-in-a-mod-rewrite-rule) at least _seems_ to do exactly what you want

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well found, I've voted to close as duplicate, and there's some useful extras points mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Transforming the text in the URL, rather than just substituting it, can be achieved using the `RewriteMap` directive. The Apache httpd user guide has [a page detailing how to use RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html), which includes this example:

> Redirect a URI to an all-lowercase version of itself
>
> RewriteMap lc int:tolower 
> RewriteRule "(.*)" "${lc:$1}" [R]

The first line defines the map "lc" to be the built-in "tolower" function, and the second line applies that map to the back-reference $1 in a rewrite rule.

So in your example, you could use:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/*$ x/{lc:$1}.html [L,NC,END]
```

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong but I could not get it to work......RewriteMap uc int:toupper.....RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/*$  contents/processed/en/{uc:$1}/{uc:$1}.html [L,NC,END]......

Comment: The exact URL is here: https://webcodingcenter.com/HTML

Comment: even with the $ sign added, it is not working

Comment: could it be due to an older version of Apache being used?

Comment: @ChongLipPhang In the question, you said you wanted to convert *from* uppercase *to* lowercase, so why are you changing the code to use "toupper" rather than keeping "tolower" as in the example? Maybe you've got info the habit of reading rules backwards (what you want to happen -> what the user sees), rather than how they actually process (what the browser sends in the request -> what the server does in response)

Comment: It was meant to be an example. My actual .htaccess file is quite big and sophisticated.

Comment: @ChongLipPhang Then start by testing that same example, before you try to combine it with your other rules; that way, you'll be able to narrow down the problem, and come up with an example for a new question if necessary.

Comment: @ChongLipPhang "My actual .htaccess file is ..." - So, you are are using `.htaccess` then (as tagged in the question)? You can't _define_ rewrite maps in `.htaccess`. These can only be defined in the server config. When you said you "could not get it to work", what exactly happened? If you tried to use `RewriteMap` in `.htaccess` then you'd get a "500 Internal Server Error" with a corresponding error logged in your server's error log. Cononicalising URLs to lowercase (or uppercase) _needs_ to be an external redirect otherwise you are potentially creating a duplicate content issue.

Comment: @ChongLipPhang "due to an older version of Apache" - What version of Apache are you using? The `END` flag requires Apache 2.4 (which you are using in your original rule), but it's probably not required. (You certainly don't need both `L` and `END` together.)